# Calculation of the number of combinations

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $5$ lamps in a line. How many combinations are there with $2$ or more on? There is $1$ combination where all lamps are turned on and $5$ where any one of them is turned on.

There are $4$ combinations when $2$ or more lamps are on. $2$ on $3$ off, $3$ on $2$ off, $4$ on $1$ off, $5$ on $0$ off. But what will be the correct answer according to the question?

Comment: There are $2^5=32$ total possible patterns. Draw them up. How many have 2 or more on?

Comment: So 26 is the answer

Comment: @zahidhasanemon  You can answer your own question, then accept it after $48$ hours have passed so that it does not remain open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2$ possibilities for a lamp: ON or OFF. For $5$ lamps there are $2^5=32$ combinations.

> There is $1$ combination where all lamps are turned on and $5$  where any one of them is turned on.

The remaining combinations have $2$ ore more lamps turned on. The number of remaining combinations is therefore $32-5-1=26.$